# How do I get child elements to scroll with the width of the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/9L503yyk/1/

What I am trying to do is get the orange children to extend beyond the right of the parent div. The parent div will be scrollable to the right but NOT up and down. There will be dynamic heights going on with jquery sortable so the children need to stay visible vertically but not horizontally.

Very simple code I have here.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">asdf</div>
    <div class="child">asdf</div>
    <div class="child">asdf</div>
    <div class="child">asdf</div>
    <div class="child">asdf</div>
    <div class="child">asdf</div>
    <div class="child">asdf</div>
    <div class="child">asdf</div>
</div>

.parent {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
.child {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    background: orange;
    margin: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `white-space:nowrap;` to your parent div.

See this updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9L503yyk/2/).

Comment: That really only works because he specified the children as `inline-block` elements. It seems like a strange way to get to scrolling horizontal.

Comment: yeah this worked for the scrolling, but unfortunately it broke the vertical sorting aspect of what I need it to do.

Comment: What do you mean by "vertical sorting aspect"?

Comment: @jrubins The OP is using `display:inline-block;` so I don't see the issue. It doesn't seem strange to me, it does what it says... it doesn't wrap to a new line when it encounters white space

Comment: yeah honestly, the white-space answer fixed the actual question. Im having trouble with a function unrelated to the question, so for that purpose, this answer is correct. I also set overscrol-x to auto which seems to also look better UI wise. Thanks @zgood :D

Comment: @YeahMKD if you post a new question for your new problem I might be able to help you

Comment: @YeahMKD also you should accept the answer if it helped you so it can help others in the future.